# How to improve runtime performance of reading file program

Tags: python, file, io

I'm currently trying to read 150 million lines (from a data file with bio-sequencing information) using Python. Currently, it's reading at 20,000 lines per second which would take about an hour and a half. I have to read through 20 of these files. Given that Python is a very high level language, would it be better to use Java to read the files instead or is the time difference not significant enough to warrant switching to another language?

The current code I'm using is:

```
lines_hashed = 0
with open(CUR_FILE) as f:
    for line in f:
       cpg = line.split("\t")
       cpg_dict[cpg[0]] = ....data....
       print lines_hashed
       lined_hashed += 1
```

The print statement is there only as a sanity that the program didn't stall anywhere. I'm assuming this is also slowing down the running time. Is there a way to check this without the print statement?

Thanks.

Comment: comment out the print statement will probably be much faster ....

Comment: Why do you need to `print lines_hashed` every line? Why not every 100,000 or 1,000,000 lines? `if lines_hashed%100000 == 0: print lines_hashed`.  Even better, use `for i, line in enumerate(f)` instead of `lines_hashed`.

Comment: not sure about python, but some classes in java are actually very slow when it comes to read **lines** because they read 1 char at a time and compare it to \n, while creating a stringbuffer by appending all the chars 1 after the other.

Comment: typically, if you know the length of you lines, using file.read(chunkSize) could be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Printing to the screen is expensive compared to disk reads.  If you must check performance as you go along, only print something out every 1000 lines or more.
2. As for using other languages, almost all languages call the OS to do the real work anyway.

Comment: CPython's file iterator is already the fastest way to deliver a line at a time:  the iterator implementation "reads in bulk" under the covers.