# Runtime extremely slow taking a string input from file compared to same individual input string?

Tags: python, file, terminal, runtime

I've finished coding my program and now I'm testing it. I've been testing my code by inputting individual input strings and it has been able to solve with the correct output within a matter of seconds. However, when taking that same input from a file of a number of input strings, my program slows down and I'm not sure if this is due to the way I'm calling the input file or if my program is slow.

However, when taking that same input from a file of a number of input strings, my program slows down and I'm not sure if this is due to the way I'm calling the input file or if my program is slow. To clarify: 
In the first one I manually input a string input while b.txt contains a file of string inputs. it was taking considerably long to solve a certain string in the file but when I tested this string individually it was solved in a matter of seconds. What could I be misunderstanding?

```
for line in sys.argv[1].split("\n"):
    if len(line) < 9:
        continue

    start = time.time()
    board = [SOME CODE HERE]
    sboard = backtrack(board)
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start

    print(total)
```

## compared to below which takes lines of input from this code segment where

```
s = open("b.txt", "r")
sl = s.read()

t=0
for line in sl.split("\n"):
    t+=1
    if len(line) < 9:
        continue
    board = [SOME CODE HERE]

    start = time.time()
    sboard = backtrack(board)
    end = time.time()
    total = end - start
    print(str(t)+": "+str(total))
```

Comment: Have you checked (e.g. with a `print(repr(...))`) that `sys.argv[1]` in the first sample contains the same as `sl` in the second?

Comment: I'm not sure what that function is I will look up on it....but for command line argument, I am just copying and pasting input strings from the given txt file so I don't think it should be different. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337133/how-to-improve-runtime-performance-of-reading-file-program I am wondering if me printing the time as I go affects the runtime?

Comment: As the printing is outside of the time measure code `start = ...` and `end = ...` it shouldn't affect the values.